# 2D array trying to display properly

Tags: java, arrays

```
package arrays;
```

import java.util.Iterator;

public class StringArray2D {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String row1[][]={{"Robert","Albert","Gilbert"},{"Fobert","Sobert","Nareg","Nari"},{"Marie","Sarie","Kharie","Aarie","Akiahsbdfuiah"}};
    display2(row1);
}

public static void display2(String x[][]){

    for (int row = 0; row < x.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < x[row].length; column++) {
            System.out.print(x[row][column] +"\t"); 
        }


        System.out.println();
    }

}
public static void display(String x[][]){
    for (int row = 0; row < x.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < x[row].length; column++) {
            System.out.println(x[row][column] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

}

hello guys ... im trying to display this 2D array properly [Proper Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZE8x.png)

but instead i get the display like this [Improper Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIuKN.png)

the method "display2" works properly , the method "display" doesnt work properly 
what am i missing ?

Comment: Do you know what the `ln` in `System.out.println` means? and how is it different from `System.out.print`?

Comment: `display()` is using `System.out.println` which prints to a newline each time.  Your code is fine.

Comment: annnn yess i got it ... didnt pay attention ... thats it ... should be System.out.print instead of System.out.println

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then use the "display2" method, what's the problem?
This is the difference:
`System.out.print(x[row][column] +"\t");`

vs

`System.out.println(x[row][column] +"\t");`

The first one writes what you provide, the second one writes it and adds a new line.